# Как запретить просматривать все файлы в Amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: загрузил картинку по адресу *****.eu-1.amazonaws.com/_st/image.png, если перейти по адресу *****.eu-1.amazonaws.com все увидят это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это скрыть?
В Bucket policy настроил так:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy163577444641",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt16655774458",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::04966640544:user/user"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-st3/*"
    }
]}
```

Access control list (ACL) Настроил так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

AWS s3 использую для хранилища файлов

Answer (score 0):

Ты настроил `Everyone (public access) = List` Какой ещё эффект ты ожидал?

---

S3 самый старый сервис, поэтому там много легаси-умолчаний, которые в более новых сервисах они уже не делали.

1. **ACL**

Это старый подход, уходящий корнями в имитирование файловой системы. Его стоит использовать только когда ты хочешь дать доступ всем. В остальных сценариях он не обеспечивает ни гибкости ни лёгкости

2. **Bucket policy**

В общем случае, в AWS доступ `Principal --(action)--> Resource` должен разрешаться на обоих концах стрелки.

В случае S3 это сделано по другому. Правый конец стрелки разрешён по умолчанию для всех принципалов из того же самого аккаунта. Так что если `arn:aws:iam::04966640544:user/user` находится в том же аккаунте, то `Allow` для него не имеет никакого смысла - этот юзер (как и все другие принципалы) и так имеет доступ к этой корзине, если этот доступ разрешён в Principal policy (левый конец стрелки).

Чтобы настроить ограниченный доступ к корзине (правый конец стрелки), надо достаточно сильно потрудиться - написать `Deny` инструкции для всех, кому хочешь запретить. К счастью, можно писать с инверсией - `Deny для всех кроме ххх`, что слегка облегчает жизнь.

---

Из твоего поста непонятно, какую цель ты преследуешь. Если цель дать доступ к корзине только одному юзеру, то надо

1. Убрать публичный доступ к корзине
2. Вообще все ACL сбросить к заводским настройкам и не трогать их никогда
3. Написать Bucket Policy, которая запрещает доступ всем, кроме определённого юзера

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-st3/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-st3"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:arn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::04966640544:user/user"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

4. В principal policy юзеру `arn:aws:iam::04966640544:user/user` вписать разрешение на `arn:aws:s3:::aws-st3`